# How to deploy safe contract with predicted config and gelato sponsored gas fee?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core, gelato

We are trying to create a Safe smart contract account for given users, based on their emails. Is it possible to use gelato, to sponsor the Safe deploy contract transaction fee?

I am following the [Protocol Kit](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit#deploy-a-safe) instructions for deploying a Safe. I'm unable to find an example of using gelato, to sponsor deploy contract transaction fee.

I created safe, with the predicted configuration as shown below.

```
const safeSdk: Safe = await Safe.create({
      ethAdapter: ethAdapter,
      predictedSafe: {
        safeAccountConfig: {
          owners: [signer1Address, singer2Address],
          threshold: 1,
        },
      },
    });
```

An option for passing sponsored gas fee not found in deploySafe method

```
safeFactory
        .deploySafe({
          safeAccountConfig,
          options: {
            gasLimit: "100000",
            gasPrice: "50",
            maxFeePerGas: "10000050",
            maxPriorityFeePerGas: "10000050",
          },
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the protocol kit does not support sponsoring deployment transactions. However, the Safe{Wallet} team recently added [seedless onboarding](https://app.safe.global/welcome?chain=gno), which allows you to do this from the UI on the Gnosis Chain. We are currently working on making this available programmatically and on all chains.

Hope this helps,
Louis